# Wordpress thumbnail settings change

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a very large Wordpress image bank (over 600 images, all in use...!) and a new development will mean that i would like to change some of the thumbnail settings.

I have at the moment

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 75, 75, true );
```

In the functions, which of course means that the thumbnail is cropped to fit. I would like to change this so that the thumbnail is scaled, rather than cropped

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 75, 75);
```

But will this change the current images i have? If not, is there a way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Regenerate Thumbnails plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) will go through your media library and re crop all your images.

Comment: See also: [AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/)